# setup Google adsense on my public live website

Tags: adsense

I am setting up google adsense on my live website. The problem is, the page where i want to paste the google adsense code is https://sitename/folder/index.php. When setting up adsense, i had to provide the site name as https://sitename as the form doesn't accept breadcrumb links and the "/". Now adsense says it can't find my https://sitename. I did posted this on the adsense community help forum but so far there has been no response.  Wondering what should i do now? Thinking  if this should help.
Create a dummy landing index.html page at my  root i.e. https://sitename
Paste the adsense code in my actual file.

Is that acceptable and viable?

Regards,

Ochen

Comment: From my understanding, you need two things to setup google adsense.

One a file ads.txt available at /ads.txt and copying and pasting a script into your site.

I think every page needs the google adsense script if you want ads on every page.

Comment: i went through the adsense technical documentations agai, it says paste the adsense code with your <head> tag section and that's pretty much it. But the pressing issue is i need to place the adsense code in my index.php which isn't  the root (site home). Needto put that on http://sitename/folder/index.php and google adsense complains that they can't find my https://sitename...